# ranking items in a list of terms

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a parallel corpus in this format:

```
parallel_corpus =
one sentence in Italian : one sentence in English
one sentence in Italian : one sentence in English
```

And I have a list of bilingual terms in this format

```
bigram_list =
Difensori dei diritti umani, libertà di espressione > Human rights defenders, freedom of expression

sgomberi forzati, violazioni dei diritti umani > forced evictions, human rights violations
```

So every line in the bilingual terms file contains terms of two languages splitted by ">"

What I want is to associate, for every line in the file above, pairs of candidate translation (term in one language beside one term in the other language). So for the first example above the bigrams will look like this:

```
('Difensori dei diritti umani','Human rights defenders')
('Difensori dei diritti umani','freedom of expression')
('libertà di espressione','Human rights defenders')
('libertà di espressione','freedom of expression')
```

Afterwards I want to estimate the mutual information for every bigrams like those above, and the bigram with high value will be chosen. I tried this code

```
for line in bigram_list.splitlines():
    n = 0
    s = 0.001
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    d = 0
    mi = ''
    bi= []
    trans = line.split(' > ')
    left =  trans[0].split(', ')
    right = trans[1].split(', ')
    for i in left:
            for j in right:
                    for line in parallel_corpus.splitlines():
                            n += 1
                            if i in line and j in line:
                                    a += 1
                            elif i in line and not j in line:
                                    b+= 1
                            elif j in line and not i in line:
                                    c+= 1
                            else:
                                    d +=1
                    mi = log(((a +s)/n)/(((b+s)/n)*((c+s)/n)))
                    bi.append((i,j,mi)) 
    print (bi)
```

This code gives the following output

```
[('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'Human rights defenders', 9.747427586368971), ('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'freedom of expression', 4.054309816276213), ('libertà di espressione', 'Human rights defenders', 1.7964873912918353), ('libertà di espressione', 'freedom of expression', 3.5916971873132355)]
[('sgomberi forzati', 'forced evictions', 9.971061859787796), ('sgomberi forzati', 'human rights violations', 5.278014664230184), ('violazioni dei diritti umani', 'forced evictions', 4.3759922075718447), ('violazioni dei diritti umani', 'human rights violations', 2.760410122135915)]
```

What I need is for every line in the bigram_list if there are pairs with the same first element, choose the one pair with high value. An example: in the following line

```
[('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'Human rights defenders', 4.747427586368971), ('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'freedom of expression', 4.054309816276213), ('libertà di espressione', 'Human rights defenders', 3.7964873912918353), ('libertà di espressione', 'freedom of expression', 3.5916971873132355)]
```

We have

```
('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'Human rights defenders', 9.747427586368971)

'Difensori dei diritti umani', 'freedom of expression', 4.054309816276213
```

So we have to choose the first pair which contain the same first element ('Difensori dei diritti umani') with the second pair, but has a high value.

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you have more than two tuples with same first element in `bigram_list`?

Comment: yes, there are many three or four  tuples with same first element in the bigram_list

Answer (score 1):

Since you want only pair which has the same first element and also the maximum value, you can create a dictionary with `first element` as key. You can iterate over the list of tuples and check if key (first element of tuple) exists. If it does check whether the value is higher than the one in dictionary and replace if true.

Here is code relevant to your example:

```
temp_dict = {}
for i in a:
    if temp_dict.has_key(i[0]):
        if (temp_dict[i[0]][2] < i[2]):
            temp_dict[i[0]] = i
    else:
        temp_dict[i[0]] = i
```

Output after iterating over both the lists in your example code:

> {'violazioni dei diritti umani': ('violazioni dei diritti umani',
>   'forced evictions', 4.375992207571844), 'Difensori dei diritti umani':
>   ('Difensori dei diritti umani', 'Human rights defenders',
>   9.747427586368971), 'sgomberi forzati': ('sgomberi forzati', 'forced evictions', 9.971061859787795), 'libert\xc3\xa0 di espressione':
>   ('libert\xc3\xa0 di espressione', 'freedom of expression',
>   3.5916971873132355)}

[Demo of your working code](https://ideone.com/ccGlfR)