# Selecting from a tuples of list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples of pairs of names, every pair has a value, in this format:

```
1.[('Carlo', 'Helen', 9), ('Carlo', 'Mary', 4), ('Jan', 'Rolly', 1), ('Renzi', 'Rolly', 3)] 
2.[('Sofy', 'Reem', 9), ('Sofy', 'David', 5),('Sofy', 'keem', 3) ('Roly', 'Tony', 4), ('Gianni', 'Tony', 2)]
3.[('Sofy', 'Reem', 9), ('Sofy', 'David', 5),('Sofy', 'keem', 3),('Roly', 'Reem', 5), ('Roly', 'David', 2),('Roly', 'keem', 3)]
```

And what I want is: for every line in the list if two or more pairs of names share one name (the first or the second name) I have to choose the pair with high value. So for the example above the output will be

```
  1-('Carlo', 'Helen', 9) 
    ('Renzi', 'Rolly', 3)
  2-('Sofy', 'Reem', 9)
    ('Roly', 'Tony', 4)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Just to clarify. This question follows from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188456/ranking-items-in-a-list-of-terms/33189222?noredirect=1#comment54186235_33189222)

Comment: What about `('Jan', 'Rolly', 1)` and `('Gianni', 'Tony', 2)`?

Comment: ('Jan', 'Rolly', 1) and ('Gianni', 'Tony', 2) will not be considered since they have a low value in comparison with the pairs which share with them one name but have a high value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not looked at ways to improve this yet, but you can do a two pass over your list. On the outer loop each item is chosen as the candidate for selection. On the inner loop, each iteam which matches in name or surname and replaces the candidate for selection if and only if its score is higher than the current candidate. At the end of the inner loop you insert your candidate to the selection list if its not already inserted.

```
def get_top_scorers(dataset):
    if dataset and all(isinstance(d, list) for d in dataset):
        return [get_top_scorers(d) for d in dataset]
    selected_list = []
    for candidate in dataset:
        chosen = candidate
        for next_candidate in dataset:
            if next_candidate == chosen:
                continue
            next_name, next_surname, next_score = next_candidate

            shares_name_with_selected = any(
                next_name == s[0] or next_surname == s[1]
                for s in selected_list
            )
            if shares_name_with_selected:
                continue

            name, surname, score = chosen
            if (name == next_name or surname == next_surname) and score < next_score:
                chosen = next_candidate

        shares_name_with_selected = any(
            chosen[0] == s[0] or chosen[1] == s[1]
            for s in selected_list
        )
        if chosen not in selected_list and not shares_name_with_selected:
            selected_list.append(chosen)
    return selected_list
```

Comment: Your answer is very suitable, but this case is not got: [('Sofy', 'Reem', 9), ('Sofy', 'David', 5),('Sofy', 'keem', 3), ('Roly', 'Reem', 4), ('Roly', 'David', 2), ('Roly', 'keem', 1)]. With your code the out put here is: [('Sofy', 'Reem', 9), ('Sofy', 'David', 5), ('Sofy', 'keem', 3)]

Comment: this pair is the needed output for the last case: ('Sofy', 'Reem', 9), ('Roly', 'Reem', 4)

Comment: But your example output share 'Reem' which is not what you want.

Comment: the output pairs can share items

Comment: You said in your question: "if two or more pairs of names share one name (the first or the second name) I have to choose the pair with high value" this means no pair can share the first name or second name. Anyway I have changed the code to reflect exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Check this example: ('Sofy', 'Reem', 9), ('Sofy', 'David', 5),('Sofy', 'keem', 3),('Roly', 'Reem', 5), ('Roly', 'David', 4),('Roly', 'keem', 3)]

Answer (score 0):

You need two functions. One is iterative grouping and the other one for finding the highest value:

```
def find_highest_pair(tuple):
    highest_value = 0
    result = []
    for pair in tuple:
        if pair[2] > highest_value:
            highest_value = pair[2]
            result = pair
    return result

def grouping(tuple,n):
    stack = []
    result = []
    backup = []
    if tuple:
        check_pair = tuple.pop(0)
        backup = tuple
        if tuple:
            if check_pair[n] == tuple[0][n]:
                stack.append(tuple[0])
                tuple.pop(0)
        if not stack and len(tuple) > 0:
            return grouping(backup,n)
    stack.append(check_pair)
    result = find_highest_pair(stack)
    return result


tuple1 = [('Carlo', 'Helen', 9), ('Carlo', 'Mary', 4), ('Jan', 'Rolly', 1), ('Renzi', 'Rolly', 3)]
tuple2 = [('Sofy', 'Reem', 9), ('Sofy', 'David', 5), ('Sofy', 'keem', 3), ('Roly', 'Tony', 4), ('Gianni', 'Tony', 2)]

print "1:"
print grouping(tuple1,0)
print grouping(tuple1,1)
print "2:"
print grouping(tuple2,0)
print grouping(tuple2,1)
```

Comment: print find_highest_pair(tuple1) gives the output ('Carlo', 'Helen', 9), but the needed output is 
('Carlo', 'Helen', 9) 
    ('Renzi', 'Rolly', 3)

Comment: @user3573552 `('Renzi', 'Rolly', 3)` is not the lowest. What is your criteria for picking this element? Not lowest, not highest so what?

Comment: what needed is not only the highest value in the list, but the the high value only between the pairs which share one name

Comment: @user3573552 OK wait.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def fix_list(list_name):
    delete_list = []
    for i in range(len(list_name)):
        for j in range(len(list_name[i])):
            for k in range(1,len(list_name)):
                if i == k:
                    pass
                else:
                    if list_name[i][j] == list_name[k][j]:
                        if list_name[i][2] >= list_name[k][2]:
                            delete_list.append(list_name[k])
    list_name = [item for item in list_name if item not in delete_list]
    print list_name

    #Use return instead of print if you want to assign the new list to something

fix_list(list1)
fix_list(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 # this contains both lists
lt = [('Carlo', 'Helen', 9), ('Carlo', 'Mary', 4), ('Jan', 'Rolly', 1), ('Renzi', 'Rolly', 3),
                      ('Sofy', 'Reem', 9), ('Sofy', 'David', 5),('Sofy', 'keem', 3), ('Roly', 'Tony', 4), ('Gianni', 'Tony', 2)]

           def max_value_tuples(tuple_list):
            # find max value tuples in the list of tuple
            import itertools as it
            import operator as op
            groups = []

            # group by first element
            for k, g in it.groupby(tuple_list, key=op.itemgetter(0)):
                groups.append(list(g))
            # group by second element
            for k, g in it.groupby(tuple_list, key=op.itemgetter(1)):
                groups.append(list(g))

            final = []
            # leave out idividiual tuples
            for el in groups:
                if len(el) > 1:
                    final.append(el)

            result = []
            # sort and print with highest scrores
            for el in final:
                el = sorted(el, key=op.itemgetter(2))
                result.append(el[-1])

            return result

        print(max_value_tuples(lt))

        [('Carlo', 'Helen', 9), ('Sofy', 'Reem', 9), ('Renzi', 'Rolly', 3), ('Roly', 'Tony', 4)]

    with this and your astfile, you could do:

    all_lists = []
    for x in astfile:
        x_list = max_value_tuples(x)
        all_lists.append(x_list)
```

Comment: And if It has the format : [[('Carlo', 'Helen', 9), ('Carlo', 'Mary', 4), ('Jan', 'Rolly', 1) ] [('Carlo', 'Helen', 9), ('Carlo', 'Mary', 4), ('Jan', 'Rolly', 1) ]]?

Comment: @user3573552 I have just updated. Take a look. It is the list of tuples. The same format as your original lists.

Comment: In my case the file of It is a list of tuples, so I use ast. So I have to use: For x in ast(file): x. Here x is equal a It in your code. How can I combine the loop  For x in ast(file): x with your code?

Comment: @user3573552  if each x is lt in my code, and you need to process the whole file, you have to put my script into a function f and use something like for x in ast(file): f(x). If you want I can make a function out of the script.

Comment: Can you please make this function to be combined with your code